# Image fades on the SSRS report

Tags: ssrs

We have a SSRS report built using Report Builder 3. There is a coloured logo on top of this report which is displayed correctly when see the report on screen, print it or export it to Word. However when the report is exported to pdf, the image gets faded and seems transparent. The image is embeded in the report and the image file type is `.jpg`. W

[image]

Why is it happening? How can I prevent it?

Comment: Have you tried using a different format for the file, say PNG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon kindly suggested, I changed the format of the image to .png and the issue is resolved on the spot.